# How to concatenate two videos (one without audio, one with audio) with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i video1.avi -i video2.avi -filter complex “[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]” -map “[v]” -map “[a]” output_video.avi

video1.avi ---> this video don't audio stream, only has video stream
video2.avi ---> has video and audio streams

[Errors]

Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v] [0:a:0] [1:v] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.

How can I concatenate these two videos?

use the following commands, can concentrate these two videos, but the output video hasnot audio, how to solve this problem?

ffmpeg.exe -i video1.avi -y 1.ts

ffmpeg.exe -i video2.avi -y 2.ts

ffmpeg.exe -i concat:1.ts|2.ts -f output.mp4

Comment: Show complete output of `ffmpeg -i video1.avi -i video2.avi`. It will display info about these inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Laravel and this code work for me:

**Without audio:**

```
exec("ffmpeg -i " . $URLVIDEO1 . " -i " . $URLVIDEO2 . " -filter_complex \"[0:v:0] [1:v:0] concat=n=2:v=1 [v]\" -map \"[v]\" " . $URLVIDEOFINAL);
```

**With audio:**

```
exec("ffmpeg -i " . $URLVIDEO1 . " -i " . $URLVIDEO2 . " -filter_complex \"[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]\" -map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\" " . $URLVIDEOFINAL);
```

Obviously, the original variables are not named that way. I hope I help you